# Combine Provider (Pad) and ChangeNotifier (Provider) in main.dart and PageView Controller error multiple scroll views

Tags: flutter, provider, bloc, pageviews

Someone may have been in a similar case.

I am using the Bloc Pattern Provider (singleton), and also the ChangeNotifierProvider.
When you instantiate them from different child widgets they work well separately.
But I would like to instantiate them from root main.dart.

I am trying this and it seems to be going well

```
//Provider Bloc Patern myapp1/blocs/provider_bloc.dart
//This Provider is used to manage other widgets
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:provider/single_child_widget.dart';
    
    class ProviderBloc extends InheritedWidget{        
      //Singleton
      static ProviderBloc _instancia;
      factory ProviderBloc({Key key, SingleChildWidget child}){
        if (_instancia==null){
          _instancia = new ProviderBloc._internal(key: key, child: child);
        }
        return _instancia;
      }
      ProviderBloc._internal({ Key key, SingleChildWidget child})
        : super(key: key, child: child);
    
      @override
      bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedWidget oldWidget) => true;        
    }
```

in my main class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myapp1/blocs/provider_bloc.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ProviderBloc(
            child: ChangeNotifierProvider(
           create: (_) => new MainProvider(),
           child: MaterialApp(
           ...*rest of the code*
```

My class MainProvider

```
//This Provider is used to mainly manage the PageController, and other widgets
    class MainProvider with ChangeNotifier{
      int _currentPage = 1;
      PageController _pageController = new PageController();
      PageController get pageController => this._pageController;
    
      int get currentPage => this._currentPage;  
      set currentPage( int val ) {
        this._currentPage = val;
        _pageController.animateToPage(val, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1), curve: Curves.easeOut );
        notifyListeners(); 
     }
```

Finally, the problem is in my Home widget where I have the PageView controlled by the pageController of the MainProvider class

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
    MainProvider mainProvider;
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        mainProvider = Provider.of<MainProvider>(context);
    
        return Scaffold(
                    resizeToAvoidBottomInset : true,        
                    resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
                    body: PageView(
                      controller: mainProvider.pageController,      
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(),
                        Container(),
                        Container(),
    
                      ],
                    ),
                    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                        child: Icon(
                            Icons.search,
                          ),
                          onPressed: (){
                                    mainProvider.currentPage = 0;
                          }
                      ),
           ...*rest of the code*
```

When I press the FloatingActionButton to change the currentPage of the PageView, it throws error

```
════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart':
Failed assertion: line 111 pos 12: '_positions.length == 1'
```

And I don't understand why, if I don't have that pageController used in any other additional widget

Comment: Why do you have a `scrollController` inside another `ChangeNotifier`? I don't see any good reason to do so. This is just bad architecture. Did you check [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) ?

Comment: Basically I do it to change the page from other Children Widgets, I saw it in some examples.
Or there will be some other better way to do it so it can work together with my Provider Bloc?

Answer (score 0):

PageController Is already a ChangeNotifier, there is no need to wrap it inside other ChangeNotifier class, why not try creating it and pass it to a ChangeNotifierProvider.value?

```
  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  PageController _pageController = PageController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ProviderBloc(
        child: ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
       value: _pageController,
       child: MaterialApp(
       ...*rest of the code*
```

In the home page

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
PageController pageController;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    pageController = Provider.of<PageController>(context, listen: false);

    return Scaffold(
                resizeToAvoidBottomInset : true,        
                resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
                body: PageView(
                  controller: pageController,      
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(),
                    Container(),
                    Container(),

                  ],
                ),
                floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                    child: Icon(
                        Icons.search,
                      ),
                      onPressed: (){
                                pageController.animateToPage(0, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1), curve: Curves.easeOut );
    
                      }
                  ),
       ...*rest of the code*
```

Comment: Hello EdwynZN
The idea seems good .. I will try it. However, I wonder how I would do it for the other objects I have inside MainProvider, so that they can be used by other children widgets. I had the idea to handle the pageController and other objects inside the MainProvider, since other children are going to make changes to the pageController

Comment: Do the objects depend on the value of the pagecontroller? You could make a ChangeNotifierProxyProvider so it updates when the page controller changes

Comment: they don't depend on the pageController, but I have get and set with notifyListener
--
   bool _editPage = false;
   bool get editPage => this._editPage;
   set editPage (bool val) {
     this._editPage = val;
     notifyListeners ();
    }

Comment: In that case just have 2 ChangeNotifierProvider in a MultiProvider